# How To Import Project Android Studio

Tags: android

how to import project using Android Studio?when i click import project it will not load any project or gradle and suddently stuck and i have to manually open task manager and end application,any solution for this.

Comment: Check : https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: i need help,i know the screen tell me to locate the gradle project file but it dint show any patch it just keep loading i cant locate my project.